# Refinement options... do custom columns have to be managed metadata or can they be attributed to free form text or "choices"?

Tags: column, managed-metadata, refinement-panel

In order to make it a managed property, does the site column have to be "Managed Metadata" or can it be free form text?

Answer (score 0):

The list columns can be of any type, but if you are creating a new managed property in your search schema, there are only a few types that you can create. They are:

- Text
- Integer
- Decimal
- Date and Time
- Yes/No
- Double precision float
- Binary

Most likely then, your list column of managed metadata or choice is going to be mapped to a Managed property of type Text. If you are working in the SharePoint Online space, you can use one of the `RefinableStringXX` fields to map your crawled list property to in order to use it in the refinement panel without having to create a new managed property.